# R select values for each group

Tags: r, dplyr, min

For each combination of WEEK and GROUP I wish to find the day (1 or 2) when SCORE is lowest for TYPE == 'M' and then keep the TYPE == 'M' and TYPE == 'E' value on that same day.

```
HAVE = data.frame("WEEK" = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4),
"GROUP" = c('A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B'),
"SCORE" = c(29, 10, 19, 11, 28, 38, 23, 27, 32, 19, 32, 26, 35, 27, 39, 51, 43, 12, 35, 29, 14, 47, 12, 36, 17, 11, 24, 19, 19, 12, 33, 7),
"DAY" = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2),
"TYPE" = c('M', 'E', 'M', 'E', 'M', 'E', 'M', 'E', 'M', 'E', 'M', 'E', 'M', 'E', 'M', 'E', 'M', 'E', 'M', 'E', 'M', 'E', 'M', 'E', 'M', 'E', 'M', 'E', 'M', 'E', 'M', 'E'))


WANT=data.frame("WEEK"=c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4),
"GROUP"=c('A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B'),
"SCORE"=c(19, 11, 23, 27, 32, 19, 35, 27, 35, 29, 12, 36, 17, 11, 19, 12),
"DAY"=c(2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1),
"TYPE"=c('M', 'E', 'M', 'E', 'M', 'E', 'M', 'E', 'M', 'E', 'M', 'E', 'M', 'E', 'M', 'E'),
"SCORE.MIN"=c(1, NA, 1, NA, 1, NA, 1, NA, 1, NA, 1, NA, 1, NA, 1, NA))
```

I have 'HAVE' and wish to create 'WANT'

For each combination of WEEK and GROUP, select the DAY when TYPE = M and SCORE is lowest. This I am able to do by

```
WANT.ATTEMPT = HAVE %>%
group_by(WEEK, GROUP) %>%
mutate(SCORE.MIN = ifelse(TYPE == 'M', min(SCORE), NA))
```

HOWEVER what I wish for is the dataset WANT where as you see I group by WEEK and GROUP and find the DAY when SCORE is minimum for TYPE == 'M' but I also keep the SCORE for TYPE == 'E' for the same day

Comment: WEEK/GROUP 3A isn‘t clear because Minimum score is 32 which is true for Day 1 and 2.

Comment: @deschen is it possible to just select the first one then when there are ties?

Comment: See my update. We need to wrap the previous code into a `first` command.

Comment: Does one of the solutions below solve your problem? If so, please click on "accept answer".

Answer (score 2):

Update to prevent ties.

You can do:

```
HAVE %>%
  group_by(WEEK, GROUP) %>%
  filter(DAY == first(DAY[SCORE == min(SCORE[TYPE == 'M'])]) | TYPE == 'E') %>%
  filter(DAY %in% DAY[TYPE == 'M']) %>%
  ungroup()

# A tibble: 16 x 5
    WEEK GROUP SCORE   DAY TYPE 
   <dbl> <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>
 1     1 A        19     2 M    
 2     1 A        11     2 E    
 3     2 A        23     2 M    
 4     2 A        27     2 E    
 5     3 A        32     1 M    
 6     3 A        19     1 E    
 7     4 A        35     1 M    
 8     4 A        27     1 E    
 9     1 B        35     2 M    
10     1 B        29     2 E    
11     2 B        12     2 M    
12     2 B        36     2 E    
13     3 B        17     1 M    
14     3 B        11     1 E    
15     4 B        19     1 M    
16     4 B        12     1 E
```

Comment: Thank you and my last question is if there is a tie like there is in WEEK 3 for GROUP A can we take just the first one?

Comment: @bvowe if this or any other solution solves your problem, please consider flagging them as your accepted answer!

Answer (score 1):

We could also `arrange` first before grouping and then do the `filter`

```
library(dplyr)
HAVE %>%
   arrange(WEEK, GROUP, TYPE != 'M', SCORE) %>%
   group_by(WEEK, GROUP) %>% 
   filter(DAY %in% DAY[TYPE == "M"][1]) %>%
   ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 16 × 5
    WEEK GROUP SCORE   DAY TYPE 
   <dbl> <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>
 1     1 A        19     2 M    
 2     1 A        11     2 E    
 3     1 B        35     2 M    
 4     1 B        29     2 E    
 5     2 A        23     2 M    
 6     2 A        27     2 E    
 7     2 B        12     2 M    
 8     2 B        36     2 E    
 9     3 A        32     1 M    
10     3 A        19     1 E    
11     3 B        17     1 M    
12     3 B        11     1 E    
13     4 A        35     1 M    
14     4 A        27     1 E    
15     4 B        19     1 M    
16     4 B        12     1 E
```